# How do I switch from Android AVD to real hardware on Mac Eclipse-SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb, android-virtual-device

I am using Eclipse on Mac with Android SDK.  I have the emulator working with my code and today I borrowed an Android that I would like to test on.

I have run 'adb devices' from the command line, but I think the problem is more fundamental at the USB hardware detection level.

What tools do I use to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable **USB debugging** on your device.

1. On Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under **Settings > Applications >      Development.**
2. On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in **Settings > Developer options.**
3. As stated by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47123/dan-carlson) .. On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to **Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options and then enable USB Debugging**

Comment: This question is ancient :O  I know I resolved the issue but never went back to this question.  Thanks for reading and answering.

Comment: @mobibob Nevermind, Though the question is ancient, it will help some one in need.

Comment: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options and then enable USB Debugging. (from http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)